# Getting rid of commonalities in array

Tags: ruby

I have these arrays:

```
x = ['a','b','c','d']
y = ['b','c','e']
```

I'd like to get rid of the commonalities in `x` and `y` and ignore the non-commonalities in `y`.

Ideally, when I do something to the two arrays, I would get `['a','d']`.

Is there something that does this in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
y = [:b, :c, :e]
x - y                  # [:a, :d]
```

The `-` method, "array difference", returns a new array that is a copy of the original array,
removing any items that also appear in the second one.